# Dynamo Table Correct Throughput handling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have sort of a problem of handling throughput in dynamodb table.

If i set a throughput of 500 WCU in a specific table, does it mean that we have to pay that WCU even if its seldomly consumed? We usually add 2000-4000 data to that table at least once a week. Am i right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll have to pay for the capacity even if it's unused. You could look into [DynamoDB Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/AutoScaling.html) to automatically scale up and down your capacity based on utilization.

Comment: Understood. But even though i auto scale it, it will still throttle.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, have you read [How Amazon DynamoDB adaptive capacity accommodates uneven data access patterns (or, why what you know about DynamoDB might be outdated)](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-amazon-dynamodb-adaptive-capacity-accommodates-uneven-data-access-patterns-or-why-what-you-know-about-dynamodb-might-be-outdated/) yet?